# Retrieving the name of wear device

Tags: android, wear-os

I would like to retrieve the name of the wear device connected, as "Gear Live 02xx".

Can I use the wear API to achieve this?

Using this:

```
node.getDisplayName();
```

I receive a String as 4750237895-4553-4343-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official API to retrieve the name of the wearable device that is shown when the watch is first booted, such as G WATCH 1234 or MOTO 360 1234.

This may change in the future, but if you want to get a similar name right now, you need to do something like this:

```
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    String btAddress = "No Bluetooth";
    if (btAdapter != null)
      btAddress = btAdapter.getAddress();

    // Reconstitute the pairing device name from the model and the last 4 digits of the bluetooth MAC
    String wearName;
    if ((btAddress != null) && (!btAddress.equals("No Bluetooth"))) {
        wearName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
        String[] tokens = btAddress.split(":");
        wearName += " " + tokens[4] + tokens[5];
        wearName = wearName.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        wearName = "No Bluetooth";
    }
```

Comment: Excited to know what will be the result? if we are using Android Wear Preview App !

Answer (score 4):

Why not using bluetooth api?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#QueryingPairedDevices

the API description is not so clear:
a human readable description of the node. Sometimes generated from the bluetooth device name

"Sometimes" is not that good explanation... converting your string Hex2ASCII seems like:

GP#xESCC and too far from Gear Live name...

I used this for the convertion:
http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm

Comment: Currently, may be it is the only way. I would avoid to use BT API and use only the WEAR API...

Answer (score 3):

You can use *Build.MODEL* and *Build.BRAND* (on the Wear side).

With an LG G Watch, it will return you respectively "G Watch" and "lge".
If you want to retrieve it from the handheld, I think you (should) know how to communicate between both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the "02xx" is in your question, but to get the model of the wear device just use the Build.MODEL value. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

This would need to be executed on the wear device itself and shared with your mobile app via the Message framework: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html